# How to certificate an UWP .appxbundle?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, certificate, signtool

I'm creating a UWP app. I'm packaging it in the VS, and I get the .appxbundle. When I install the app using the .appxbundle, I don't receive any issue (probably because I've trust with my own certificate). But when I pass to another person the .appxbundle, the others cannot install it.
I've tried using the signtool.exe. I used this template: `SignTool sign /fd hashAlgorithm /a /f "C:\signingCert.pfx" "C:\filepath.appx"`. I've received the "correct message", the app is trusted. But now, when I open the .appxbundle, I receive the issue that this app is not trusted. And it's the only .appxbundle that is trusted, because the others versions of the same app that I don't trust are "trusted" for Windows.
Any help for this?
Thanks!

Comment: during package creating you [can select the certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#generate-an-app-package) on the target systems import your certificate

Comment: Yes, I've done this, and I've selected the certificate that I have "installed" on my computer. But in others computers this don't works.

Answer (score 1):

SignTool is a command line tool used to digitally sign an app package or bundle with a certificate. The certificate can either be created by the user (for testing purposes) or issued by a company (for distribution).

`SignTool` can't make the app with full trust permission that could install without certificate. You could regard `SignTool` as matching box that binding specific the certificate with appx package. And it's necessary to install the certificate before install appx package.

If you do want to install appx without certificate, we suggest you [publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/app-submissions) your app to Microsoft App Store.

Comment: So, if I don't publish the app to the Microsoft App Store, no other will could install my UWP app?

Comment: Yep, you could package the appx and certificate together and told customer install the certificate before install appx.

Comment: I've tried it, but this don't work. I send the .appxbundle and the certificate together to a friend, and nothing. He installed the certificate, and nothing. The same message, it's not trusted.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing this in the VS. I made the . appxbundle here.

Comment: Could you share the detail about how to install the certificate ?

Comment: What steps do you need?

Comment: Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#install-your-app-package-by-double-clicking).

Comment: I'll try using the PowerShell, but this is not the solution needed.

Comment: Does the powershell work in your side? And do you have any updates?

Comment: Hey, my friend doesn't answer me, I think yes, the powershell will work, but it's not the solution I need.

Comment: Could you share the steps how to install the certificate?

Comment: Yes, give me a moment and I put them into the question.

Comment: Here are the images from installing it: https://imgur.com/a/l4sp21M